# Creating a color gradient grid with javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

I am trying to create a variable grid of colors, using Javascript. The rule is that adjacent colors MUST always be similar (no green touching red, for example).

I managed to create something pretty close to what I wanted, but there are a few things that are still bothering me, and I was not able to work around them.

1. There is a prevalence of blue/red over green. There's no "dark green", for example. This is probably because of my "algorithm", but I wasn't able to change it to make green as prevalent as the other two colors without messing with the whole grid.
2. All colors should be different from one another (adding this after @Mr.Polywhirl's helpful answer, but that created some blocks of equal colors).
3. I would prefer that colors would converge to lighter tones in the center, instead of going dark.

**This is what I have achieved so far:**

```js
const COLUMNS = 30;
const ROWS = 16;
const TOTAL = COLUMNS * ROWS;

const generateRed = (step) => {
  return 0 + step * (255 / TOTAL);
}

const generateGreen = (step) => {
  return 255 - step * (255 / ROWS);
}

const generateBlue = (step) => {
  return  255 - step * (255 / COLUMNS);
}

function generateColorStrip(row) {
  const colors = [];
  for (let column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++) {
    const r = generateRed(column * ROWS);
    const g = generateGreen(row);
    const b = generateBlue(column);
    colors.push(`rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`); 
  }
  return colors;
}

function generateColorStrips() {
  let colors = [];
   for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
     colors = [...colors, ...generateColorStrip(row)]
   }
  return colors;
}

const colors = generateColorStrips();

colors.forEach(color => {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor=color;
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    document.body.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${COLUMNS}, auto)`;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  max-height: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  gap: 1px;
  width: min-content;
}

div {
  height: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

**This is what I would love to achieve, somehow:**

[image: a rainbow gradient]

Any tips on how I could change this code to achieve those goals?

Comment: Have you tried using `hsl` color mode instead of `rgb`? What is your desired gradient supposed to look like?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl -> Yes, HSL made it harder to follow the rule of "adjacent colors MUST be similar", but I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl -> Adding an image to show the desired gradient was a good call. I just did that.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get is by using the HSL color model and calculating a vector (magnitude and direction).

- Essentially a radial gradient
- Hue is the direction and lightness is the magnitude
- I inverted the x-scale and rotated by -2π/3

This is the closest I could achieve:

```js
const
  gradientEl = document.querySelector('.gradient'),
  COLS = 30, ROWS = 16,
  MAX_MAGNITUDE = Math.max(COLS, ROWS) / 2,
  MIN_MAGNITUDE = Math.min(COLS, ROWS) / 2;

const toDegrees = (radians) => radians * (180 / Math.PI);

const generateColorStrips = () => {
  const colors = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      const dx = row - Math.floor(ROWS / 2);
      const dy = col - Math.floor(COLS / 2);
      const magnitude = Math.min(Math.hypot(dx, dy), MIN_MAGNITUDE);
      const hue = Math.floor(toDegrees(Math.atan2(-dx, dy) - (Math.PI * (2/3))));
      const lightness = Math.floor((1 - (magnitude / MAX_MAGNITUDE)) * 100);
      colors.push(`hsl(${hue}, 90%, ${lightness}%)`); 
    }
  }
  return colors;
}

generateColorStrips().forEach(color => {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('swatch');
  newDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
  gradientEl.appendChild(newDiv);
  Object.assign(gradientEl.style, {
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${COLS}, auto)`,
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gradient {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1px;
}

.swatch {
  height: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

I am wondering if you can simulate CSS layer blending of two gradients.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}

.drawing {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#layer-0 {
  background: #FFF;
}

#layer-1 {
  background: linear-gradient(5deg, rgba(0,255,0,1.0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 50%, rgba(255,0,0,1.0) 100%);
}

#layer-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(95deg, rgba(255,255,0,1.0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1.0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="drawing">
  <div class="layer" id="layer-0"></div>
  <div class="layer" id="layer-1"></div>
  <div class="layer" id="layer-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's nice! The problem is that, when you remove the gap, you'll see that there's a bunch of colors (specially in the blue part of the gradient) that seems really close (or equal) one to another. I'll try playing with your code to see if I can get closer to what I need. I'll mark your answer as correct, if I'm able to get there with it. :)

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo In your desired gradient it looks like you have 4 points near each edge: top = red (90° ~ π/2), right = blue (0°), bottom = green (270° ~ 3π/2), and left = yellow (180° ~ π). Maybe if you interpolate between each quadrant to fill in the gaps, you can achieve this. Uses the axis to determine which quadrant the color falls into. As my answer stands, a radial gradient between RGB displays a triangle in a square. What you want is a sort of RYGB color space between each axis. I am not sure how to phrase that any better.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I will work on that!

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo I am trying to convert the angle to fit the following [color scale](https://i.imgur.com/wZoih7W.png). Instead of a 60/60/60/60/60/60 ratio, I think you need a 75/75/75/30/75/30 scale or something like that. You want to pinch the cyan and magenta slices, or eliminate them entirely... [like this](https://i.imgur.com/4PzBsnQ.png).

Comment: Although this was not the answer I was looking for, you deserved the bounty for the time you spent on this. Thanks. :)